# Javascript switch not working

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I have the folowing code:

```
var windowNow = window.localStorage.getItem("windowNow");
switch(windowNow)
{
case 1:
    var link = "http://www.zive.sk/rss/sc-47/default.aspx";
    var listviewID = "feedZive";
    break;
case 2:
    var link = "http://mobilmania.azet.sk/rss/sc-47/default.aspx";
    var listviewID = "feedMobil";
    break;
case 3: 
    var link = "http://www.automoto.sk/rss";
    var listviewID = "feedAuto";
    break;
}
```

and I know that `windowNow === 1` because I have checked it with alert and also to be sure that it realy is 1 I checked it with `if(windowNow == 1) { alert ("Window now is 1");}` and it worked. But it is not working inside my switch (checked it with alerts).

Comment: try to give double quatation for case like this case "1"

Comment: to really verify the value use if(windowNow === 1)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The items in the `localStorage` are always strings. Use `case "1"` and so on.

The problem with your check is that is a loose check, which doesn't check for the data type. You should have tried

```
if(windowNow === 1) { alert ("Window now is 1");}
```

Notice the triple `=`.

Answer (score 2):

Do not declare variables inside a switch. Declare them outside the switch and assign inside. Also convert to an integer first.

```
var windowNow = parseInt(window.localStorage.getItem("windowNow"), 10), link, listviewID;
switch(windowNow)
{
case 1:
    link = "http://www.zive.sk/rss/sc-47/default.aspx";
    listviewID = "feedZive";
    break;
case 2:
    link = "http://mobilmania.azet.sk/rss/sc-47/default.aspx";
    listviewID = "feedMobil";
    break;
case 3: 
    link = "http://www.automoto.sk/rss";
    listviewID = "feedAuto";
    break;
default:
    // default assignment.
}
```

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: That really isn't relevant to his question, before the added code change.  First sentence should still be removed

Comment: @Dameo The type conversion to an integer is not relevant to the difference between == and ===?